# Is there an upper limit to the number of bind calls in a JOOQ batch statement?

Tags: java, jooq, batch-insert

We use batch statements when inserting as follows:

```
BatchBindStep batch = create.batch(create
   .insertInto(PERSON, ID, NAME)
   .values((Integer) null, null));

for (Person p : peopleToInsert) {
  batch.bind(p.getId(), p.getName());
}
batch.execute();
```

This has worked well in the past when inserting several thousands of objects. However, it raises a few questions:

1. Is there an upper limit to the number of `.bind()` calls for a batch?
2. If so, what does the limit depend on?
3. It seems to be possible to call `.bind()` again after having executed `.execute()`. Will `.execute()` clear previously bound values?

To clarify the last question: after the following code has executed...

```
BatchBindStep batch = create.batch(create
   .insertInto(PERSON, ID, NAME)
   .values((Integer) null, null));

batch.bind(1, "A");
batch.bind(2, "B");
batch.extecute();
batch.bind(3, "C");
batch.bind(4, "D");
batch.execute();
```

which result should I expect?

```
a)        b)
ID NAME   ID NAME
-------   -------
 1 A       1 A
 2 B       2 B
 3 C       1 A
 4 D       2 B
           3 C
           4 D
```

Unfortunately, neither the [Javadoc](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.7.0/org/jooq/Batch.html#execute--) nor [the documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.7/manual/sql-execution/batch-execution/) discuss this particular usage pattern.

(I am asking this particular question because if I `.execute()` every 1000 binds or so to avoid said limit, I need to know whether I can reuse the `batch` objects for several `.execute()` calls or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is valid as of jOOQ 3.7

> 1. Is there an upper limit to the number of .bind() calls for a batch?

Not in jOOQ, but your JDBC driver / database server might have such limits.

> 2. If so, what does the limit depend on?

Several things:

- jOOQ keeps an intermediate buffer for all of the bound variables and binds them to a JDBC batch statement all at once. So, your client memory might also impose an upper limit. But jOOQ doesn't have any limits per se.
- Your JDBC driver might know such limits ([see also this article on how jOOQ handles limits in non-batch statements](http://blog.jooq.org/2013/04/28/rare-uses-of-a-controlflowexception/)). Known limits are:

  - SQLite: 999 bind variables per statement
  - Ingres 10.1.0: 1024 bind variables per statement
  - Sybase ASE 15.5: 2000 bind variables per statement
  - SQL Server 2008: 2100 bind variables per statement

  I'm not aware of any such limits in Oracle, but there probably are.
- Batch size is not the only thing you should tune when inserting large amounts of data. There are also:

  - Bulk size, i.e. the number of rows inserted per statement
  - Batch size, i.e. the number of statements per batch sent to the server
  - Commit size, i.e. the number of batches committed in a single transaction

  Tuning your insertion boils down to tuning all of the above. jOOQ ships with a dedicated importing API where you can tune all of the above: http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/importing
- You should also consider bypassing SQL for insertions into a loader table, e.g. using [Oracle's SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/SUTIL/ldr_params.htm). Once you've inserted all data, you can move it to the "real table" using [PL/SQL's `FORALL` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm), which is PL/SQL's  version of JDBC's batch statement. This approach will out perform anything you do with JDBC.

> 3. It seems to be possible to call .bind() again after having executed .execute(). Will .execute() clear previously bound values?

Currently, `execute()` will not clear the bind values. You'll need to create a new statement instead. This is unlikely to change, as future jOOQ versions will favour immutability in its API design.